# Politer word to refer to a 'cleaner'

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

Is there a polite way to refer to someone who is responsible for cleaning at work?

Comment: His name works.

Comment: For example if you were writing a job advertisement?

Comment: Habitat Contaminant Removal Executive?

Comment: I actually think "cleaner", or "We are looking for someone to clean our offices" or similar is fine in a job advert.  True, it's not a job that comes with high status attached, but bending over backwards to obscure that only highlights it IMHO.  (I'm thinking of Subway's cringe-inducing "Sandwich Artist" job title...)

Comment: Housekeeping staff

Comment: If you want to be exceptionally polite, why not call him a  "steward".

Comment: I have a vague impression that *cleaner* is more common in BrE, and less used in AmE.

Comment: Yes.  Cleaner is not used in AmE.  At least not for that.  Janitor would be the most common term.  In AmE, "Cleaner" is used in movies to refer to a special-agent/criminal type character to comes in to clean-up botched jobs, a la Winston Wolf in Pulp Fiction or Victor in Point Of No Return (both played by Harvey Keitel)

Comment: "Cleaner" can also mean "security guard" (since the former are often assumed or suspected to be a de facto latter).

Comment: If a potential hire is put off by your use of *any* of the standard terms for this type of position, then you probably don't want to put up with their clearly overinflated sense of importance anyway. Just call the job what it is and you'll get plenty of applications from people who aren't offended by the facts.

Comment: I wrote the following and then realized how close it is to Kevin's comment, but I'll post it anyway...  In my AmEng experience, I don't remember hearing "cleaner" as a title for a human. The noun "the cleaner" would refer to a solvent or surfactant. The job title with which I am familiar with no euphamism is "Janitor". Though one might be a member of the "Cleaning Crew"

Comment: @Kevin, I knew that "janitor" is more common in American than in the rest of English, but I thought it translated to something more like "caretaker".  That is, the guy who general looks after a building, fixing things or cleaning if needed.  But the cleaners thespecialist crew comes in with industrial strength hoovers, detergents etc.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala,  janitor, at least in my experience, is almost exclusively cleaning.  Someone who did things like repairs would be referred to as a handyman or maintenance man. Or, in corporate speak, maintenance staff or facilities manager.

Comment: Cleaning technician?

Comment: @Kevin: That is unfortunate, because it originally means "doorman", from *ianua* "[double-doored] entrance", from *Janus* the two-faced god.

Comment: If cleaning is what the main part of what they do (both in importance and in time consumption), then call them a cleaner (possibly part of the cleaning staff or personnel?).
Why would you assume "cleaner" is impolite? Call them a cleaner, but say it with gratitude, say it knowing that cleaning is an honourable and worth while job.

Answer (score 51):

Some people might find it subtly insulting if you call them "custodians" or "facilitators", or whatever, when they are really cleaners, as if their true job were shameful. If you clean, you're a cleaner, and there is nothing embarrassing about it that needs to be concealed. Further, euphemisms and needlessly using big words is considered ugly by almost all style books. So just call him a **cleaner**.

Comment: Agreed, what would be wrong with making things clean? Some nonsense like `Localized Sanitation Executive` just obfuscates both meaning and some perceived inferiority. Like all over exaggerated "political correctness" this practice actually perpetuates what it seeks to avoid.

Comment: Except that I've rarely, if ever, heard "cleaner" actually used that way. In practice, "custodians" is much more common, or "house-keepers," or "cleaning crew."

Comment: @user124384: I have never heard "custodian" used that way. Apparently there are regional differences.

Answer (score 15):

*Janitor*, *caretaker*, or *custodian* could also be used, but those jobs tend to be broader in scope than just cleaning: maintenance and other aspects of looking after a building can also be included.

Comment: "Janitor" is, in a sense, less polite.  "Custodian" is the more PC term that is often used.

Comment: Can you give a reference to "less polite"? Why would [job sites](http://www.indeed.com/q-Janitor-l-New-York-jobs.html) use it if it were?

Comment: It's the age-old thing -- any word for a relatively low-level & dirty job or some other somewhat demeaning role in society will acquire a negative aura.  So new words (eg, "custodian" instead of "janitor") are used.  Using the old words effectively "demotes" the person designated.

Comment: @HotLicks And how regularly do new words have to be made up in order to prevent this? I mean one can take insult by _anything_, and usually you're better of _not_ trying to circumvent words that _might_ be interpreted as offensive, since that mere attempt might be an insult as well...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - Probably every 50 years or so.  Consider the many euphemistic synonyms for "crap house".  (I didn't make this rule, society did.)

Comment: Regarding this evolution (devolution) of words, consider these "idiot, imbecile, moron, retard(ed)..."  http://www.dailywritingtips.com/idiots-imbeciles-and-morons/

Comment: +1 I think "caretaker" is a nice balance. "Janitor" might be seen as slightly negative, and "custodian" sounds like we're being a bit too political.

Comment: It depends where you are. But certainly here in London, caretaker has a more specific meaning. My mum went out with a caretaker at a school. He actually had a house near the school that came with the job and he was very much an odd job man around the school, he also opened the school up in the morning, locked it up at night, and generally took care of the school. I don't think he did much routine cleaning. They had cleaners for that. Although, I think if there was a spillage he would sometimes be called upon to sort it out. But if you mean cleaner - say cleaner!

Comment: @TecBrat: The *euphemism treadmill*. That is something we should try to avoid, because it doesn't work and results in ugliness. Orwell, amongst others, was famously against doublespeak, using language to try to effect political goals.

Comment: @Cerberus: Doubleplusgood! ;-)

Comment: @PeterK.: Waaah kill me now!

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps, 'Facilities staff' would fit the bill.

Examples of how to use this:

- "The kind facility staff provided me with an additional waste paper bin."
- "The facility staff member smiled at me and asked how I was."

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion, could you provide any references to show how it is used in the "real world"?

Comment: Well, the "facilities staff" where I work often refuse to clean things, as "its not their job."

Comment: Just "facilities" is much more common, e.g. "I called facilities and they cleaned up the mess in the bathroom."

Answer (score 8):

1. If I wanted a cleaning job and saw an advertisement for a "Facilities Generalist" or a "Habitat Contaminant Removal Executive" I would pass the advert by because I would have no idea what it meant.  The last one in particular I would imagine required specialist technical training.
   Advertise for a cleaner.
2. If you have a particular individual in mind who is already in post, I suggest you ask that person what job title they prefer. Some people will want a fancy title, others will be happy with something simple.

Comment: In case you missed it, _Habitat Contaminant Removal Executive_ was **sarcasm**, made up on the spot.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think chasty understood the sarcasm. I think they simply wanted to point out that sugar-coating things will only make matters worse.

Answer (score 8):

"Housekeeping" is the general position name at the hospital I used to work for.

**Housekeeping** — [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/housekeeping.html)

> General care, cleanliness, orderliness, and maintenance of business or property. Good housekeeping is an important consideration in underwriting of fire hazard and other forms of insurance, as well as in certification by fire, health, and industrial safety agencies.
>
> *"You should have a good **housekeeping staff** in your office so that it has a good professional feel to it."*
> *"The **housekeeping** showed up very early and I told them to go away and come back in an hour or two, when I was gone."*

Answer (score 6):

**Cleaner** doesn't sound rude.

I would imagine that you are going to get a lot more applications for a **Cleaner** ad versus a **Premises Upkeep Engineer** ad

Answer (score 1):

How about ***office cleaner***?

> [AVOIDING SEXIST LANGUAGE](http://www.nytimes.com/1991/06/11/news/nonsexist-dictionary-spells-out-rudeness.html?pagewanted=all)
>
> Instead of *cleaning lady*, *cleaning woman*, consider using *housecleaner*, *office cleaner*, *housekeeper*
>
> [Source: Random House Webster's College Dictionary, ed. 1991](http://old.brusov.am/docs/Eng_Phon_Gram-course-arm/Social%20History%20of%20English.doc)
>
> *The Office Cleaner is responsible for maintaining the overall cleanliness of the facility.*
>
> [opiny.org](http://www.opiny.org/career-opportunities/167)

Comment: Yes, this seems to match more closely than any other what the OP requested. 'cleaner' by itself (or with modifiers) is not impolite or disparaged at all. And the people who come late at night to clean offices after hours are currently called 'office cleaners'. 'Janitor' has become a bit disparaging and 'custodian' is used more often nowadays instead. An office cleaner often implies female, and janitor/custodian male.

Answer (score -1):

*Late answer 2 monthes after the question*: a **cleaning operative** has surprisingly not been proposed.

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you said whether it was BrEng or AmEng, and if you included some support/reference for your answer.

Answer (score -2):

I'm surprised the term "floor manager" hasn't been offered. I've seen it used for the toilet cleaning personnel in e.g. cinema's here.

Answer (score -3):

Another possibility not mentioned is concierge.  While usually not associated with cleaning duties, in France where the word originated the concierge was (and in some cases still is) responsible for the janitorial duties in many small hotels.  As mentioned in other posts it is not the sole responsibility but included among others.